# PHP function to check if browser referer is empty?

Tags: php

I was using this function

```
ereg('http://.',$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) != 1
```

To check if the visitor clicked a link or did enter directly to this particular page.

I see now that ereg is deprecated, but have no knowledge of php to convert this to maybe preg_match?

Is there any other way to check if the referer is empty?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 5):

Your regex accepts only referers that start with `http://`. So if somebody would navigate to your script from a `https://` page, the referer would register as empty. Any specific reason for that?

If not, using [`empty()`](http://www.php.net/empty) will always work:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
```

Answer (score 0):

`empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])`

Answer (score 0):

For empty:

```
!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

For a protocol:

```
strlen(parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_SCHEME)) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (preg_match('#http://#', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
  // match found...
}
```

Or if you want to check whether or not it is empty, use the [`empty`](http://www.php.net/empty) function:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
  // match found...
}
```